# what is the meaning of this JQuery statement?

Tags: jquery

I was working on building an animated search bar using CSS3 JQuery and HTML5, and I came across a code on the web that handles this issue. However, there is a line of code I did not catch the meaning of:

```
if ($(selector).closest('.class').length === 0)) {
   // do something

}
```

Why are we checking if the length of an element supposed to be null ?

Comment: Which part do you not understand? `$(selector)`, `closest('.class')` or `length`?

Comment: You can check [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: It was the length part. I am sorry I wasn't very specific.

Comment: .length is the preferred way to find size of a jquery object. The size() is deprecated. See https://api.jquery.com/size/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jQuery selector or function used for traversing (ie. `children()`, `closest()` or `find()`) always returns a jQuery object, so it's never `null` or `undefined`.
This object then contains a set of elements that match your selector and/or traversal functions and it also has a `length` property which indicates the size of this set.
So even if your selector would match nothing, you'd still have a jQuery object with a length of 0. That's why the length property is used to determine whether there are any results or not.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the `Selector` (including `Selector` element itself),it will traveling up the DOM tree and check whether is there any element with `.class`. if northing found, it will execute the code. The following is a example code in the official documentation. I use it to explain your question

```
<ul id="one" class="level-1">
  <li class="item-i">I</li>
  <li id="ii" class="item-i">II
    <ul class="level-2">
      <li class="item-a">A</li>
      <li class="item-b">B
        <ul class="level-3">
          <li class="item-1">1</li>
          <li class="item-2">2</li>
          <li class="item-3">3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-c">C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-i">III</li>
</ul>
```

If you try this you will see that 1 as the output since it finds a ul element while traveling up the DOM tree. Once it found one, it stops.

```
 console.log($("li.item-a").closest("ul").length);
```

1. To prove that its search including element itself

   ```
   console.log($("li.item-a").closest("li"));
   ```

   Will output

   `Object { 0: <li.item-a>, length: 1, prevObject: Object }`
2. To prove that he return as soon as he found one

   ```
       console.log($("li.item-a").closest("li.item-i"));
   ```

   Will output

   ```
       Object { 0: <li#ii.item-i>, length: 1, prevObject: Object }
   ```

**Edit**

It will not be null.

```
console.log($("li.item-a").closest("li.noClass"));
```

Will return

```
Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object }
```

[For More info about .closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 1):

In simple language...
$(selector) find the element
.closest find the closest element to the above element

for eg -

`$(selector).closest('form').submit();`

will submit the closest form to the selector element

and ' === ' operator matches data-type and the value unlike == that only matches value